# Relation between IVT, Connectedness, Completness in Metric Space, LUB

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The motive behind this question is:

1. In an ordered field LUB <=> IVT.
   [Is the IVT equivalent to completeness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388577/is-the-ivt-equivalent-to-completeness/2388654?noredirect=1#comment7754467_2388654)
2. Connected Metric Space X does have IVP i.e "all continuous function f:M⟶R that admit a positive value
   and a negative value, also admit a c∈M such that f(c)=0".
   I read that the converse is also true.
   [If M a metric space with the property of Intermediate Value. Show that M is connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032885/if-m-a-metric-space-with-the-property-of-intermediate-value-show-that-m-is-conn)

So LUB <=> IVT <=> Connectedness (Is this correct?)

3. Does the Complete Metric Space also have this property?

I am trying to find is a connection between Completion in Metric Space and Connectedness in Metric Space.

Also, Cauchy Completeness in R is weaker than LUB in R.(Cauchy Completion + Archimedian Property $\implies$ LUB)

So does Completion in $\mathbb{R}$ is stronger than Completion in Metric Spaces?

Basically I am trying to see the connections between all the the properties of Real Analysis and Metric Spaces.

Comment: The two point space is obviously complete as a metric space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between completeness and connectedness. The middle-thirds Cantor set is complete in the usual metric and is zero-dimensional and hence totally disconnected. The irrationals are not complete in the usual metric, but they are a $G_\delta$-subset of the complete metric space $\Bbb R$, so there is a metric on them that generates the usual topology and in which they are complete. (Every $G_\delta$-set in a complete metric space is completely metrizable.)